# On Toshiba Satellite L650, is it possible to move from a 32 bit to a 64 bit using recovery media creator?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, 64-bit, license, toshiba-laptop

Purchased a Toshiba satellite L650 sometime in November 2009. It came with **4 GB** RAM (not enough key bounce while I posted first, oops :-( ), 284 GB HDD, DVD drive and 2 USB ports, 1 sATA/USB port and all the usual slots.

It came pre-installed with Windows 7 Home Premium. When I activated the machine, I was asked to choose 32 bit or 64 bit version. Not having access to the Net to make an informed choice, I decided to choose 32-bit for safety's sake. I've since regretted it, for it left 1GB RAM virtually unusable on the machine!

Two questions for the forum:

1. For that laptop, is it possible to use the recovery media creator and roll back to a 64 bit Win 7 Home Premium OS on the machine ?
2. The existing HDD is 284GB capacity, and it is showing signs of age. I think it needs to be replaced (soonish, I might add). I am thinking of buying a 1 TB laptop HDD to replace the existing one. Is it possible to use the Toshiba recovery software creator to reinstall the Win 7 Home Premium OS (64 bit) on the new HDD? Or should I use some kind of disk mirroring software (Macrium, Paragon, etc) to mirror the previous HDD on the new one?

EDIT 2a:
I should have mentioned this. I have made a media recovery creator on a 16 GB USB pen drive. And yes, my laptop is USB bootable.

EDIT: I typed my title last, and I got a few "possible" threads based on my title keywords. I am also looking at those right now. So, If this thread is already discussed and I missed it, please direct me to the thread.

Thanks.

Comment: how much RAM is on your machine?  its missing from your 2nd sentence

Comment: @Keltari one can assume that there is 4GB of RAM installed, since he later on says "it left 1GB RAM virtually unusable...". Since 32-bit has only utilizes 3GB it would be safe to assume 4GB. Just my assumption anyways...

Comment: @both, it is indeed 4gb. Due to insufficient key bounce the 4 didn't get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using this Recovery Media Creator a necessity? I'd suggest you just save your important files to an external HDD, then pop in the new one, install Win7 Home Premium x64 untouched from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft), activate using the key from the COA sticker on the laptop's bottom and copy your files back. (If the sticker's missing or faded, use [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to first recover your current installation's key.)

Alternately just install Win7 on the new HDD, activate, then copy your files directly from the old HDD which you've placed into a USB enclosure.

Imaging your existing installation is not recommended in this case since upgrading from the 32 to 64-bit version of Windows is not possible and requires a fresh install of all your apps anyway.

You can choose to keep the Recovery Media Creator and recovery partition around on the old HDD, but I don't really see the advantage of doing so. After you've installed an untouched copy of Win7 (that'll lack any crapware Toshiba includes) and all your apps, you can *then* image your new HDD to an external drive as part of your backup strategy.

Comment: I hadn't checked in a while. And I did go with the Recovery Creator which was a completely ludicrous way of doing things.... The whole thing is more hassle than worth it, it made me jump hoops that should not be jumped in the first place, and the net result is "not so good". The bloody laptop still takes aaages to boot up and even more aaaages to log me in... The screen goes black with the "busy cursor" and everything lags. One important question: Surely I will need the laptop's special Toshiba drivers to make it work the way it worked earlier, right? Or is Win7 driver support good enough?

Comment: In other words, I am tempted to give your idea a try, but I would be interested to know if driver support for the Toshiba Laptop's hardware is provided OOTB by Windows? If not, the recovery creator becomes a "necessary (and worst) evil" :( It is a very poorly designed software, honestly!

Comment: If 64-bit drivers are available I'm sure they must be on the Toshiba site. Search for your laptop model, download *all* the applicable drivers and keep them ready on a USB stick/drive.

Comment: Ah **that** old trick! Le more downloading, Le more sigh... Le fiddling with "box" files! Say, you don't happen to know how to speed up boot and load times, do you?

Comment: So, I'll try asking that as a separate question... Not sure if I want to go through the hassle of creating ISOs out of yet-another-convoluted file format once again! :( Perhaps, all I am interested in is to reduce my boot and login times!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "box" files. All you have to do is keep the driver installer EXEs ready. The best way to speed up boot times is to use a fast drive, such as an SSD. Other than that, ensure you don't have useless programs loading on startup and if you're an experienced user you can try disabling/setting to manual unnecessary services. I'm sure there are questions that already discuss this, else feel free to post a new one. Finally, if this answer helped you don't forget to accept it!

Comment: ^^ From the links you posted above for downloading Microsoft legally and installing, the files are supplied as "box" files. And there is a special procedure to convert them into ISO. It was all there as part of your link above. Just too much hassle. I just purchased a 1 TB HDD and I do not have a SSD. My cold boot to login screen is nearly 1 min, and login to readiness is over 1 min... I have had a free run of removing many services using MSCONFIG tool. Absolutely no change in boot times. It is a brand new install over a brand new HDD, and I have used MSCONFIG to optimise the startup. Le Sigh!

Comment: I'm guessing you missed all those direct Digital River links to the Home Premium **ISOs**? ;)

Comment: Yes... I missed that.... More le sigh! :( I might accept this solution, but for me, it came a little too late... I had already taken the recovery media route. But given my hair-raising experience with that stupid tool, this solution seems to hold more promise... I hope this one will accept pre-existing partitions, unlike stupid Toshiba tool which refused to work unless it had the entire 1 TB HDD to itself X( ! I will accept it as an answer, but I wish it came earlier. To compound issues, Toshiba drivers are scattered all over the place! Filing this for future, and focus on sorting boot times!